# Topic Subscription for Durable Queues

Tags: solace

I wanted to configure a durable queue in one VPN to subscribe to topics from different VPNs.  Is it possible to do so?  What is the topic expression syntax to refer to topics from other VPNs?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a VPN bridge to bridge messages from one VPN to another.

The purpose of VPNs is to segregate applications into separate messaging domains. Therefore, messages published onto a VPN cannot be seen by another.

A message VPN bridge allows for the delivery of messages that match an explicit set of topic subscriptions from a remote Message VPN to a local Message VPN.

Please refer to the Solace documentation for a full description of how VPN bridges work, and how to configure them.
https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Solace_Messaging_Platform_Feature_Guide/Working_With_Message_VPN_Bridges.html#